# Pop-OS 22.04 with nvidia-driver-525 fails to suspend on a hybrid laptop

Tags: nvidia, suspend, pop-os

The fact that after surfing dozens of help posts I failed to reach a solution indicates how diverse the problem is.

#### Problem:

I'm using **Pop-OS 22.04 LTS** on my HP Pavilion laptop which features **Intel UHD 620** and **Nvidia GeForce 940MX** graphics. My system features **gdm** with **x11** and my graphics driver is **nvidia-driver-525**.

My system was working fine during **Pop-OS 21.04** but after upgrading to **22.04** I'm facing issue with system suspend. Here is my journalctl log

```
$ journalctl -b 1 -g suspend
Apr 20 16:13:35 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1183]: (**) Option "SuspendTime" "0"
Apr 20 16:13:46 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1183]: (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
Apr 20 16:13:46 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2841]: (**) Option "SuspendTime" "0"
Apr 20 16:14:11 pop-os sudo[3709]:    meraj : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/meraj ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl suspend
Apr 20 16:14:11 pop-os ModemManager[985]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Apr 20 16:14:16 pop-os systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system suspend actions...
Apr 20 16:14:16 pop-os suspend[3778]: nvidia-suspend.service
Apr 20 16:14:16 pop-os logger[3778]: <13>Apr 20 16:14:16 suspend: nvidia-suspend.service
Apr 20 16:14:16 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2841]: (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
Apr 20 16:14:16 pop-os kernel:  uvm_suspend+0xa6/0x1f0 [nvidia_uvm]
Apr 20 16:14:16 pop-os kernel:  uvm_suspend_entry.part.0+0xbb/0xf0 [nvidia_uvm]
Apr 20 16:14:16 pop-os kernel:  uvm_suspend_entry+0x27/0x30 [nvidia_uvm]
Apr 20 16:14:16 pop-os kernel:  nv_uvm_suspend+0x2e/0x50 [nvidia]
Apr 20 16:14:16 pop-os kernel:  nv_procfs_write_suspend+0x106/0x1c0 [nvidia]
Apr 20 16:14:16 pop-os systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Apr 20 16:14:16 pop-os systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Apr 20 16:14:16 pop-os systemd[1]: Failed to start NVIDIA system suspend actions.
Apr 20 16:14:16 pop-os systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Apr 20 16:14:16 pop-os systemd-sleep[3792]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Apr 20 16:14:16 pop-os kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Apr 20 16:14:18 pop-os kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Apr 20 16:14:18 pop-os kernel: NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: PreserveVideoMemoryAllocations module parameter is set. System Power Management attempted without driver procfs suspend interface. Please refer to the 'Configuring Power Management Support' section in the driver README.
Apr 20 16:14:18 pop-os kernel: nvidia 0000:01:00.0: PM: pci_pm_suspend(): nv_pmops_suspend+0x0/0x30 [nvidia] returns -5
Apr 20 16:14:18 pop-os kernel: nvidia 0000:01:00.0: PM: dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x1b0 returns -5
Apr 20 16:14:18 pop-os kernel: nvidia 0000:01:00.0: PM: failed to suspend async: error -5
Apr 20 16:14:18 pop-os kernel: PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
Apr 20 16:14:18 pop-os kernel: PM: suspend exit
Apr 20 16:14:18 pop-os kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Apr 20 16:14:18 pop-os kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Apr 20 16:14:18 pop-os kernel: NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: PreserveVideoMemoryAllocations module parameter is set. System Power Management attempted without driver procfs suspend interface. Please refer to the 'Configuring Power Management Support' section in the driver README.
Apr 20 16:14:18 pop-os kernel: nvidia 0000:01:00.0: PM: pci_pm_suspend(): nv_pmops_suspend+0x0/0x30 [nvidia] returns -5
Apr 20 16:14:18 pop-os kernel: nvidia 0000:01:00.0: PM: dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x1b0 returns -5
Apr 20 16:14:18 pop-os kernel: nvidia 0000:01:00.0: PM: failed to suspend async: error -5
Apr 20 16:14:18 pop-os kernel: PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
Apr 20 16:14:19 pop-os kernel: PM: suspend exit
Apr 20 16:15:49 pop-os systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

#### Attempt 1

My first approach was to disable nvidia suspend, hibernate and resume services altogether, following this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404946/978279)

```
$ sudo systemctl disable nvidia-hibernate.service nvidia-resume.service nvidia-suspend.service
```

This resulted in system freezing during suspend, only displaying the lockscreen, and not responding to any inputs except force shutdown (holding the power button).

#### Attempt 2

So I enabled the services back and follow [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA/Tips_and_tricks#Preserve_video_memory_after_suspend) on Arch wiki.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-power-management.conf

options nvidia NVreg_PreserveVideoMemoryAllocations=1 NVreg_TemporaryFilePath=/var/tmp
```

Then I updated the initramfs using

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)
```

After rebooting I tried to suspend but ran into the same error again with the same log described before.

#### Attempt 3

My final attempt was to uninstall nvidia-driver completely from the system and install an older one (**nvidia-driver-470**). But after manual installation, nvidia-smi was failing to communicate with the nvidia-driver, forcing me to reinstall the OS, leading me back to where I was.

I will be very much helped if someone can assist be with fixing the problem. In the meantime, I'll investigate on my own and update. Thanks in advance.